# How to make the input dates which user type in the prompt show in report ? MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, report

I already done that query and generate report accordingly between the "start date" and "end date" that user enter in the prompt box. But how do i set the value entered by user will show in the report generated?

Comment: Very simple. Please show your query - because you are already asking the user for the date.

Answer (score 0):

Have two textboxes in the report using the names of the parameters as *ControlSource*:

```
=[Start Date]
=[End Date]
```